# Extracting(Clipping) in Google Earth Engine

Tags: extract, google-earth-engine, satellite-image

I am working with Google earth Engine and I am trying to extract/Filter (clip)  pixels in a band using another image (band). I calculated NDVI and created a threshold value that rendered an image with NDVI > 0.3 but I wanted to extract the corresponding pixels in the visible an NIR bands.
Here is snippet code.

```js
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2');
var s2_filtered = s2.filterDate('2017-01-01', '2017-12-31')
                  .filterBounds(geometry) //custom Geometry

var calcNDVI = function(x){
  var ndvi4 = x.normalizedDifference(["B5", "B4"]).rename("ndvi")
  return x.addBands(ndvi)
}

var ndviCollection = s2_filtered.map(calcNDVI)
var maxNDVI = mosaic.select("ndvi");
var threshold = maxNDVI.gt(0.3)
```

I am at the point where I wanted to clip the corresponding pixels in "B", "G", "R" and "NIR" bands using the threshold variable(image). Obviously, I'm stuck here. Please let me know if there is with a way to filter/clip pixels of one band using another band with in GEE. The task is similar to using Clipper in QGIS which is the options I am left with if this doesn't work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd be better if you ask this question in gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `threshold` is a mask, so you have to mask out pixels in the mosaic using the threshold mask, right? If that is the case, simply update the mask of the image:

```js
var masked = maxNDVI.updateMask(threshold)
```

Comment: Thanks! I that was very helpful. I used this variable (masked) to mask out the bands in the mosaic image just like I wanted them.